# echart data point gradient color

Tags: javascript, linechart, echarts

I am trying to make a gradient line chart, The issue is with tooltip legend color and color of data points, they appear in brown gradient which was the default.

I was able to change the tooltip color, anyhow that is not the actual data point color but able to fix it to one color at least. whereas the points on the line do not pick up the color of the line.

Can someone point me in right direction?

[image: screen capture]

```
 var dom = document.getElementById("container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
var app = {};


var option;



var data = [["2020-06-05",116],["2020-06-06",129],["2020-06-07",135],["2020-06-08",86],["2020-06-09",73],["2020-06-10",85],["2020-06-11",73],["2020-06-12",68],["2020-06-13",92],["2020-06-14",130],["2020-06-15",245],["2020-06-16",139],["2020-06-17",115],["2020-06-18",111],["2020-06-19",309],["2020-06-20",206],["2020-06-21",137],["2020-06-22",128],["2020-06-23",85],["2020-06-24",94],["2020-06-25",71],["2020-06-26",106],["2020-06-27",84],["2020-06-28",93],["2020-06-29",85],["2020-06-30",73],["2020-07-01",83],["2020-07-02",125],["2020-07-03",107],["2020-07-04",82],["2020-07-05",44],["2020-07-06",72],["2020-07-07",106],["2020-07-08",107],["2020-07-09",66],["2020-07-10",91],["2020-07-11",92],["2020-07-12",113],["2020-07-13",107],["2020-07-14",131],["2020-07-15",111],["2020-07-16",64],["2020-07-17",69],["2020-07-18",88],["2020-07-19",77],["2020-07-20",83],["2020-07-21",111],["2020-07-22",57],["2020-07-23",55],["2020-07-24",60]];

var dateList = data.map(function (item) {
    return item[0];
});
var valueList = data.map(function (item) {
    return item[1];
});

option = {
    color: {
                type: 'linear',
                x: 0, y: 1,x2:0,y2:0,
                colorStops: [{
                    offset: 0, color: '#00d4ff' // color at 0% position
                }, {
                    offset: 1, color: '#090979' // color at 100% position
                }],
                global:true
            },
    // Make gradient line here
    visualMap: [{
        show: true,
        type: 'continuous',
        seriesIndex: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 400
    }],
    title: [{
        left: 'center',
        text: 'Gradient along the y axis'
    }],
    xAxis: [{
        data: dateList,
        axisPointer: {
        label:{
            color:['#5470c6'],
            }
        },
        axisLabel: {
            formatter: function (value) {
                return moment(value).format("MMM YY");
                // And other formatter tool (e.g. moment) can be used here.
            }
        }
    }],
    yAxis: [{
            type: 'value',
            axisPointer: {
            label:{
                color:['#5470c6'],
                }
            }
    }],
    grid: [{
        width:'auto',
        height:'auto'
    }],
    tooltip : {
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {
            animation: true,
        },
        formatter: function (params) {
            var colorSpan = color => '<span style="display:inline-block;margin-right:5px;border-radius:10px;width:9px;height:9px;background-color:' + color + '"></span>';
            let rez = '<p>' + params[0].axisValue + '</p>';
            console.log(params); //quite useful for debug
            params.forEach(item => {
           //     console.log(item); //quite useful for debug
                var xx = '<p>'   + colorSpan('#00d4ff') + ' ' + item.seriesName + ': ' + item.data + '</p>'
                rez += xx;
            });
            console.log(rez);
            return rez;
        }        
    },
    series: [{
        color:['#5470c6', '#91cc75', '#fac858', '#ee6666', '#73c0de', '#3ba272', '#fc8452', '#9a60b4', '#ea7ccc'],
        type: 'line',
        showSymbol: false,
        data: valueList,
    //  smooth: true,
        label:{
            show:true,
            position:'top'
        },
        lineStyle:{
            color: {
                type: 'linear',
                x: 0, y: 1,x2:0,y2:0,
                colorStops: [{
                    offset: 0, color: '#00d4ff' // color at 0% position
                }, {
                    offset: 1, color: '#090979' // color at 100% position
                }],
                global:false
            }
        }
    }]
};
console.log(myChart);
if (option && typeof option === 'object') {
    myChart.setOption(option);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `gradientColor` array to echarts options. Now echart will take care of changing color of tooltip and data point. You can also remove your custom tooltip formatted function.

`gradientColor: ["#00d4ff", "#090979"]`

Here the complete options object:

```
var data = [];

var dateList = data.map(function(item) {
  return item[0];
});
var valueList = data.map(function(item) {
  return item[1];
});

option = {
  gradientColor: ["#00d4ff", "#090979"],
  // Make gradient line here
  visualMap: [
    {
      show: true,
      type: "continuous",
      seriesIndex: 0,
      min: 0,
      max: 400
    }
  ],
  title: [
    {
      left: "center",
      text: "Gradient along the y axis"
    }
  ],
  xAxis: [
    {
      data: dateList,
      axisPointer: {
        label: {
          color: ["#5470c6"]
        }
      },
      axisLabel: {
        formatter: function(value) {
          return moment(value).format("MMM YY");
          // And other formatter tool (e.g. moment) can be used here.
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: "value",
      axisPointer: {
        label: {
          color: ["#5470c6"]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  grid: [
    {
      width: "auto",
      height: "auto"
    }
  ],
  tooltip: {
    trigger: "axis",
    axisPointer: {
      animation: true
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      type: "line",
      showSymbol: false,
      data: valueList,
      //  smooth: true,
      label: {
        show: true,
        position: "top"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```